# Read More button in asp.net mvc3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, database, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on asp.net mvc3 application and have many records coming from database. I want to display only 10 records first then user can click on button to see next 10 records and so on. Like facebook wall posting more records.  How can I implement this thing in my application ?  I am using this to get 10 records but I want to display all records using more record button

Comment: google "infinite scrolling"

Comment: @HusseinNazzal This isn't quite infinite scrolling since he wants records to appear on button click, not scroll.

Comment: I would use either an ajax call back to the controller to get the next set of records or look into jquery paging where you load all of the records and just show the different pieces depending on the button click

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going...

---

Assuming:

```
public class PostsViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<PostViewModel> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

Your controller might look like:

```
public class BlogController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        PostsViewModel model = new PostsViewModel 
        {
            Posts = postService.GetPosts(resultsPerPage: 10, page: 1)
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    public PartialViewResult More(Int32 page = 1)
    {
        PostsViewModel model = new PostsViewModel 
        {
            Posts = postService.GetPosts(resultsPerPage: 10, page: page)
        };
        return PartialView(model);
    }
}
```

And Views something like:

**~/Views/Blog/Index.cshtml**

```
@model PostsViewModel
@* Other page content *@
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Posts)
<div id="more"></div>
@Ajax.ActionLink("Read More", "More", "Blog", new AjaxOptions {
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore,
    UpdateTargetId = "more"
})
@* Other page content *@
```

**~/Views/Blog/More.cshtml**

```
@model PostsViewModel
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Posts)
```

**~/Views/Blog/DisplayTemplates/PostViewModel.cshtml**

```
@model PostViewModel
@* Display post itself *@
```